# How do I clone a linked list?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

Here is a basic example of a linked list that looks like this

head -> [4] -> [6] -> [8] -> None

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LL:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insert_tail(self, o):
        new_node = Node(o)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current.next != None:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_node

    def __str__(self):
        result = ''
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            result = result + str(current.data) + ", "
            current = current.next
        return result[:-2]




    def clone(self, empty):
        '''(LL, NoneType) -> LL
        '''
        empty = LL()
        current = self.head 
        while current != None:
            empty.insert_tail(None)
            current = current.next
        return empty

a = LL()
a.insert_tail(4)
a.insert_tail(6)
a.insert_tail(8)
print(a)
```

My question is, how would I clone this without mutating the original linked list in any way? Oh and I don't want to be using any built in data structures to do this , as in no list, dictionaries, tuples, and etc. (No imports as well)

EDIT: I don't want to clone the data, I just want a linked list like :

head [] -> [] -> [] -> None    (This be a clone of the one above)

Comment: Cant believe I forgot python as a tag, whoopsie

Comment: As a side note, you should really name you class as `LinkedList` or something more descriptive.

Comment: @NPE my clone method is what I managed

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your list is suboptimal. When implementing linked list you should:

1. Insert items at the beginning of the list what is `O(1)`
2. If you want to support inserting items at the end of a list you should also keep track of the last element of a list (thus inserting would be `O(1)` as well, in your case its `O(n)`).

To solve your problem you can take following approach:
Create an empty list and iterate through your existing one. For every element in existing list simply add it at the end of a new list.

Comment: Advice should be kept in comments. The OP wasn't asking how to optimize their implementation.

Comment: I havent started Algorithms yet so I do not know what you mean by O(1).

Comment: @Ali89 O(1) means that the operation is independent from length of a list (constant in time). Note, that in your case if you have N items on list, adding new item would require to iterate through whole list. This means that this operation is O(N) in time -> it requires time that is proportional to the length of a list.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to clone a linked list is to walk the list, item by item, and create a new linked list as you go, inserting new elements at tail as you normally would. Create a new instance of your `LL` class then use the `insert_tail()` method to add the items from the list you're cloning.

If you're hoping to clone your `data` attribute so that your cloned list doesn't interact with the original, then you'll have to employ deep copying in Python.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

It's worth noting that it could just be simpler to use a deep copy on your entire linked list, however, your mileage may vary depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just wana copy the pointers I don't care whats in the data. I didn't know that they werent interchangable, I made an edit.

Comment: @Ali89 I've given the answer to that; Walk the list, create a new one with the same methods by appending to the tail. You don't want to copy the pointers, you want to create new pointers; Copied pointers would point to the old linked list elements.

Comment: Hello. If you look at my new linked list in edit, my clone method. Is that correct?

Comment: No, use the methods you already have in the class. Create a new instance of `LL` and `insert_tail()` all the items from the target list you're trying to clone.

Comment: Hello. Do you mean like that?